# CMake: How to load interface classes of the main application in another cmake target?

Tags: c++, cmake

How do I load the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES of the main application, in a library (plugin) target? I know how to load the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES of a library, but I don't know how to load them without linking a library.

```
├── app
├── pluga
└── plugb
```

Comment: Linking is the only way to automatically propagating properties from one target to another. You may create *header-only* library (`add_library(... INTERFACE)`), set its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES  property and link both the application and plugins with it.

Answer (score 0):

The `target_include_directories()` command populates `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` with values given to the `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` keywords.

Targets may populate this property to publish the include directories required to compile against the headers for the target. Consuming targets can add entries to their own `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property such as `$<TARGET_PROPERTY:foo,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>` to use the include directories specified in the interface of foo.

So the answer is to use:

```
target_include_directories(pluga INTERFACE
    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:app,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
)
```

From the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html).